# Cucumber - Undefined Steps Though defined

Tags: selenium, java-8, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm creating a Simple Selenium Cucumber project and defined steps using "Lambda Expressions Constructor" way for a feature file but when I ran the CucumberTest class I'm getting failure exception as

> **There are undefined steps!**

My StepDefinition is below one

[image]
And Feature file is the below one

[image]

CucumberRunner class is below:

[image]

So please suggest me is there any different approach for calling Step Definition File if I use Lambda Expressions?

Comment: which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Eclipse...Do you know the solution for what I've asked?

Comment: What else you are getting in console with your error ? Can you please post that

Comment: Please add your code as text, not pictures

Comment: Maybe your `StepDef` class is not in a package defined in the `glue` option for the runner.

Comment: @SubOptimal nope...it is properly defined

Comment: I guess the problem is that you have `glue = { "src/test/...` where it should be a list of packages, not path names. Try `glue = { "my.project. ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment. The option `glue` expects a list of package names, not directories. Changing it from

```
glue = {"src/test/java/my.project.automation.wolfram_alpha" }
```

to

```
glue = {"my.project.automation.wolfram_alpha" }
```

will solve the issue.

Find working snippets below. Assuming following structure

```
src/test/java/my/project/automation/wolfram_alpha/StepDef.java
src/test/java/my/project/automation/wolfram_alpha/cucumberTest.java
src/test/resources/wolfram.feature
pom.xml
```

**pom.xml** (dependencies part)

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**cucumberTest.java**

```
package my.project.automation.wolfram_alpha;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = { "src/test/resources/wolfram.feature" },
        glue = {"my.project.automation.wolfram_alpha" }
)
public class cucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

**StepDef.java**

```
package my.project.automation.wolfram_alpha;

import cucumber.api.java8.En;

public class StepDef implements En {
    public StepDef() {
        Given("URL of WolframAlpha" , () -> {
            System.out.println("Given URL of WolframAlpha");
        });
        When("user logged in as {string} with {string}" , (String user, String password) -> {
            System.out.printf("When user logged in as {%s} with {%s}%n", user, password);
        });
        And("login is successful" , () -> {
            System.out.println("And login is successful");
        });
        And("user search for a {string}" , (String topic) -> {
            System.out.printf("And user search for a {%s}%n", topic);
        });
        Then("results are displayed in a creative way" , () -> {
            System.out.println("Then results are displayed in a creative way");
        });
    }
}
```

**wolfram.feature** from the question

Running the test with `mvn test` produces following output.

```
Running my.project.automation.wolfram_alpha.cucumberTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@726f3b58
Given URL of WolframAlpha
When user logged in as {user} with {password}
And login is successful
And user search for a {IDOL}
Then results are displayed in a creative way

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
5 Steps (5 passed)
```